# In iOS, how do I lower BLE connection interval?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

How do I specify a lower **BLE connection interval** in iOS?

I believe in iOS the default is 30 ms but can be lowered to 15 ms (as mentioned in 2017 WWDC Whats New In Core Bluetooth).

Apple mentioned the connection interval can be lowered but this does not seem to be documented anywhere.

I need this to be done by the **centralManager** rather than the peripheral.

Current code:

```
self.centralManager.connect(self.peripheral, options: nil)
```

I would expect the options parameter could be the right place for this, but it does not seem to be so https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager/peripheral_connection_options.

This https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheralmanager/1393277-setdesiredconnectionlatency looked promising but was for an acting peripheral rather than a central.

Is it even possible to do this using CoreBluetooth in iOS?

Comment: This has nothing to do with UI

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IOS Bluetooth Low Energy Connection Interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108608/ios-bluetooth-low-energy-connection-interval)

Comment: That is similar. Case 2 would not as the peripheral does not use the framework. But Case 1 does. I thought since these questions and answers were before WWDC 2017 that maybe things had changed. I suppose this rule that it must be determined by the peripheral is part of BLE then rather than a restriction by Apple

Comment: No it's a restriction by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

This question is not really about the Swift language, but about the CoreBluetooth framework. What they talked about in WWDC 2017 was that iOS acting as central now accepts a larger range of connection parameters requested by a peripheral. From what I know, there is no API to change the connection parameters from an app acting as BLE central.

Comment: Thanks! I thought they meant the central could now determine the interval. I'll have to mess with the peripheral then. Maybe something like editing /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/conn_min_interval will help.

Would upvote but don't have enough "reputation".