# Set Bluetooth Low Energy Connection Interval to 7.5ms (Minimum) in C#

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy, 32feet

I am connecting to a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) device from a C# console application using the [32feet InTheHand BLE library](https://github.com/inthehand/32feet/tree/main/InTheHand.BluetoothLE).

I would like to [set the connection interval to the minimum possible](https://docs.silabs.com/bluetooth/4.0/general/system-and-performance/throughput-with-bluetooth-low-energy-technology#connection-interval) (7.5ms), in order to achieve the maximum number of signals per second that is possible. (Not really relevant, but the signals are very light weight, byte or less).

At this time, my functional code looks like this, but I can't find a way to set the interval:

```
using InTheHand.Bluetooth;

IReadOnlyCollection<BluetoothDevice> discoveredDevices = await Bluetooth.ScanForDevicesAsync();
BluetoothDevice fooDevice = discoveredDevices.Single(d => d.Name == "fooDevice");

var gatt = fooDevice.Gatt;
await gatt.ConnectAsync();

GattService barService = await gatt.GetPrimaryServiceAsync(BleUuids.BAR_SERVICE);

GattCharacteristic fooChar = await barService .GetCharacteristicAsync(Guid.Parse(BleUuids.FOO_CHAR));
```

How would I set the connection interval to set messages every 7.5ms?

Comment: If you run your code on Windows platform then changing connection parameters is possible only on Windows 11 and above. Windows 10 does not support such feature. I have no idea if 32feet provides such functional but Bluetooth Framework does (for Windows 11).

Comment: Thank you Mike, I am looking at an answer linked below and it seems to indicate that you can "usually" set the interval on the device being connected to when defining the GATT, is that accurate?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108608/ios-bluetooth-low-energy-connection-interval

Comment: I do not know about iOS API, I am Windows developer. But if you connect to your peripheral from Windows PC and the peripheral sets/changes any connection parameters Windows "always" accepts them.